# Have a PHP page output a static image

Tags: php, image, png

I want a PHP to be able to send 1 of 3 images, depending on a `$_GET[]` parameter. I have the images as three separate PNGs right now, and would like the PHP script to have those embedded in it, then return the specified image. So, I want one PHP script instead of 3 images. Is this possible? I don't need to create special images on the fly, just print out one of those. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your images are in files, use PHP's [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function, and send a content-type header before outputting it:

```
<?php
$imagePaths = array(
    '1' => 'file1.png',
    '2' => 'file2.png',
    '3' => 'file3.png',
);

$type = $_GET['img'];

if ( isset($imagePaths[$type]) ) {
    $imagePath = $imagePaths[$type];
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    readfile($imagePath);
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found');
    echo 'File not found.';
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**
You could also embed your images in the script by encoding them e.g. as [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), then embed them as strings in PHP, then decode it there with [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) to deliver them:

```
<?php
$imageData = array(
    '1' => '...', // Base64-encoded data as string
    ...
);

$type = $_GET['img'];

if ( isset($imageData[$type]) ) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    echo base64_decode($imageData[$type]);
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found');
    echo 'File not found.';
}
?>
```

You could also use PHP to encode the image on the command line. Just execute this PHP script in the command line (`php script.php image1.png image2.png image3.png > output.php`) and save its output, and incorporate it into your script:

```
<?php
$imageData = array();

foreach ($argv as $index => $imagePath)
    $imageData[(string)($index + 1)] = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imagePath));

echo '$imageData = '.var_export($imageData, true).';';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Archimedix!! I'll take a look at that, it's just what I need!

Comment: With an approach like this (`header()` outputs Content-type expectation and using `readfile`) resulted in IE9 defaulting to Quirks as the Document Mode. Can anything be done to tell IE not to freak, it's just an image? [Example](http://www.homeeducatormom.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/orange-scarf1.jpg) (Not my site)

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested the following, but it should work. Use this script to get PHP code that will contain the image data.

To get the image:

```
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents("image.png"));
// The string $image now contains your image data.
```

Get this (potentially big) string in your code where you want the image, for each image. Print it and copy it then paste it. Import it as a text file over the web. That's up to you.

Then, to print the image (only the image as if the PHP script were the image), do:

```
header("content-type: image/png");
print base64_decode($image);
```

Of course, you would put each image data in an array or something like that.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It works. First I have tried it with newdoc syntax and it also worked, but this solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Do this:

1. Write a php script deciding which image to output.
2. Set the appropriate headers with header() function (I.e. Content-type)
3. Open the file, read it and send it to the output stream.

Remember that you will probably lose any benefits from browser's cache with this approach...

Comment: Wouldn't that still require having the images as seperate files? Is there any way to embed them in the script?

Comment: why is he going to loose browser cache? Images are still located by unique URL with GET parameters in it.

Comment: Why would you want to embed an image into a script?

Comment: Using "data:" uris you can make it easy.

Comment: I'm doing a contest where I have to make a 1-page website, no external files. I have a couple images i have to have, so that's why I was wondering if I could embed them. Is it possible to embed them?

Answer (score 0):

A fast but not really secure nor elegant way to do it...

```
<?php
switch($_GET['type']){
 case "1":
    $image = "image1.png";
    break;
 case "2":
    $image = "image2.png";
    break;
 case "3":
    $image = "image3.png";
    break;
}
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile($image);
?>
```

**the moral of the story:** use header() and readfile() =D