# Serving up a static image in IE results in Quirks Mode

Tags: php, internet-explorer, http-headers, quirks-mode

Following the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795780/469643) I can successfully serve up png, gif, or whatever images I want but since I don't have any control over the `<!DOCTYPE>` of the page (that I know of) IE9 (and presumably others) decide that the "Document Mode" is "Quirks" as the default.

IE successfully displays the image (just a slight shadow around the edge of the document provides any clue of a problem) so maybe I should be content and disregard the dreaded quirks mode status that is given to the page created in this way.

My approach is similar to the one in the above answer:

```
# Other processing that is not output / echoed
# <-- Can something else be sent here to calm IE down?
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile($imagePath);
```

This approach results in an HTML document that looks like this according to IE's Developer Tools:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <body>
        <img src="theUrlOfThePage" />
```

Is there a way to tweak the `DOCTYPE` (or lack thereof) without getting in the way of the `header` that is sent nor the image I want to output? My attempts to pass the `DOCTYPE` at various stages of the above process just broke the ability to display the image properly.

Comment: Why don't you have control over the DocType? Do you send anything to the browser (like echo or anything) before the doctype? IE doesn't like that and jumps into quirksmode.

Comment: @putvande; thanks for the thought. I tried echoing the doctype around the two calls (`header` and `readfile`) but that corrupted what browsers expect -- straight-up image data.

Comment: the doc type goes in the html... not in the image... the image doesn't have a doctype

Comment: @Orangepill; thanks but I'm not trying to insert doctype information inside the image. What it looks like to me is that when you try to serve an image directly to the browser then you don't have control over the html any more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php DomDocument adds extra tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800459/php-domdocument-adds-extra-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Use a header template which includes the doctype:

```
<?php
echo <<<HEADER
<!doctype html>
  <html>
     <body>

HEADER;
?>
```

and a footer template which ends the file:

```
<?php
echo <<<FOOTER
  </body>
</html>
FOOTER;
?>
```

In the main file, include both as well as the existing content:

```
<?php
include('header.php')
include('content.php')
include('footer.php')
?>
```

> Use output buffering to cache the output string internally and send it to the user in one shot. In long-running scripts, you will also want to flush the output buffer periodically so that some feedback is sent to the HTTP client. This can be done with ob_end_flush(). This function also turns off output buffering, so you might want to call ob_start() again immediately after the flush.

- [Supercharge Your CSS with PHP Under the Hood](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood--net-6409)
- [Supercharging CSS, Part 3: CSS Variables](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-css-part-3-css-variables.html)
- [CSS variables with PHP – CSS compression – manifest file](http://website-tricks.net/css-variables-with-php-css-compression-manifest-file/)
- [Using Dynamic CSS](http://gtro.com/web/dyncss_e.php)
- [Creating and rendering CSS templates (eg. style.css.php)](https://www.drupal.org/node/568180)

The Link header would be useful, but only in Firefox:

- [Implement Link header](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/786562/implement-link-http-header)
- [Linking to style sheets with HTTP headers is not implemented in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20018)
- [Stylesheets referenced by the Link header are not included](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19237)
- [HTTP Headers Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287673)

Comment: Can you successfully execute `header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile($imagePath);` *after* executing your header include? I am hesitant to believe that is possible. It looks like you are not getting around the problem I posted -- that sending the header `Content-Type` conflicts with echoing or printing a `<!doctype html>`. Be sure to post your working solution if you can.

Comment: It's not a hard problem, or an original solution. If you need to execute headers after the document head, just use the output buffer. There are [many](http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-tutorials/how-to-output-images-using-php.html), [many](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/generating_dynamic_css_with_php/), [many](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2003/04/10/php_heredocs.html?page=2) examples in the wild.

Comment: I haven't had a hard time outputting images -- just keeping IE out of quirks mode when loading an image only. I also have output buffering on but there is no "header" for sending the doctype which is actually HTML. But if you try to output doctype after or before outputting the image it throws errors. Does that make sense? Much like this (in IE it will be in quirks mode by default): http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2bfd9423d69103c5269bdb01f15757cd?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG